# How can I refer to another process's port in a Procfile?

Tags: microservices, foreman, procfile

I have a Procfile that looks like this:

```
web:     ./frontend -port=$PORT -backend_addr=$BACKEND_ADDR
backend: ./backend -port=$PORT
```

I'm currently manually passing in the automatically assigned port for `backend` in `$BACKEND_ADDR`, but it seems like there ought to be a better way.  How can I make it so that `$BACKEND_ADDR` is automatically populated for me?